# UISearchBar scrolls while the UITableView is scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, scroll, uisearchbar

How to accomplish the `UISearchBar` scrolling effect like Instagram.app? The `UISearchBar` is scrolling up while the `UITableView` is scrolling up. The `UISearchBar` stop scroll down when it's origin.y equals to 0;
 [image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution is as following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.myTableview.delegate = self;
self.myTableview.dataSource = self;
self.mySearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, searchBarHeight)];
[self.myTableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(searchBarHeight, 0, 0, 0)];
[self.myTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
float move = offset.y + searchBarHeight;
if (move > -2*searchBarHeight && move <3*searchBarHeight) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect searchBarFrame = self.mySearchBar.frame;
                         searchBarFrame.origin.y = MIN(MAX(-move, -searchBarHeight), 0);

                         [self.mySearchBar setFrame:searchBarFrame];

                     }

                     completion:^(BOOL f) {

                     }];
}
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me well. Personally I decided to create UIViewController with a UISearchBar, UISearchController and UITableView all in one View in their own frames using Interface Builder and nib file. And it works nicely.

Comment: @wzbozon Does it have the same effect? Why not post an answer with your solution:)

Comment: It's hard to post. Everything is made in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

make a instance of UISearchBar and set it as tableView Header View

```
        [tableView setTableHeaderView:yourSearchBar];
```

it will now scroll with tableView